# Make a node.js server fetch an image from an external API and pass to a web client

Tags: image, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have a node.js server and client web application with a feature that displays images from Instagram's API. Instagram does not allow web applications to directly query the API. Instead, I need my Node.js server to query the Instagram API for images, and pass this image to my client application to display in the browser. What is the best way to go about this? My current approach, which I am attempting to wire up at the moment is such that the node.js server converts the image from its Instagram API url to a base64 value and passes this base 64 value to the client app, which then displays the base64 value in an image tag.

Node.js code...

```
function convertURLToBase64(url) {
  console.log('converting URL to base64');
  request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log('there was no error receiving image');
      data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');
      // console.log(data);
      return data;
    }
  });
}
```

...
          
...

Is there a better, common and recommended approach?

Comment: _"Instagram does not allow web applications to directly query the API."_ - I don't think that goes for the image URLs you get as well? Have you tried passing that URL to the client directly, and use it to create a new img element there?

Comment: Yes. I tried like this: <img width="300px" :src="<the_url>" />

And here is an example of the URL I am using https://instagram.frak2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/259497386_196643625994146_3388283263813535041_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.frak2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=UGAH4chUjEkAX-nbrdo&edm=ABZsPhsBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=2f992397bcf987ddd267a245e20a369d&oe=61A1E31B&_nc_sid=4efc9f
Note there is https:// at the beginning as you can see if you click this link.

Comment: The response headers for that URL include `cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin`, so it looks like they are blocking direct client access for some reason.

Comment: Please have a look at my follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70110896/async-await-not-functioning-properly