# async await not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, api, async-await, promise

So I'm displaying instagram posts in my client application. Instagram does not allow client applications running in a browser to directly query its API.
So I set up a node.js server to fetch the image urls, convert them to base64 encoded format and pass this output to my client application.

Here is my server code.
You can see that I fetch all instagram posts that match the specified hashtag variable value. I know that this query runs successfully. In the body of the response, each post (I am calling these "edge"s by Instagram's API convention) contains a nested parameter called thumbnail_src. This is a url pointing to the image. In my map function, I pass this url into a second function called convertURLToBase64 that should do what the name of the function indicates.

However, my response is empty. What is going on? How do I fix this? async/await and promises are tricky. Thanks

```
async function getHashTaggedPosts(hashtag) {
  url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/?__a=1";
  return await axios.get(url, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } }).then(
    async (response) => {
      let edges = response.data.graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges;
      updatedEdges = edges.map(async (edge) => {
        edge.imageBase64 = await convertURLToBase64(edge.node.thumbnail_src);
        return edge;
      })
      console.log('updatedEdges: ' + updatedEdges);
      return updatedEdges;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log("error: " + error.message);
    }
  );
}

async function convertURLToBase64(url) {
  console.log('converting URL ' + url + ' to base64');
  await request.get(url, async function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log('there was no error receiving image');
      data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');
      // console.log(data);
      return data;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `await` takes a promise and resolves it. But you already resolved it by calling `then`. You're combining two different asynchronous patterns and they are colliding. Pick one pattern (await everywhere or then everywhere) and that may help with the debugging. (It is legal to combine the two patterns but you have to be careful how you do it.)

Answer (score 1):

With callbacks, promises an ansyc/await you are mixing three different techniques for handling asyc code which is always not a very good idea.

As already pointed out, in `getHashTaggedPosts` you are mixing `await` and `.then` in one statement, which I would rewrite to stick to one single syntax.

Also you are using the array `.map` function with a async callback, meaning it will return promises and not the actual values you're expecting.
Here you need to rewrite this part as well. If you want to stick to the `.map` function, you can use `Promise.all`.

Then in `convertURLToBase64` you are awaiting the `request.get`method wich seems to use a callback, so it will not return a promise that you can await.
Instead you are returning from the callback function with `return data;` but this will not be received anywhere.
As a rule of thumb, never return anything from a callback.

I can't test your code, but try something more like this:

```js
    async function getHashTaggedPosts(hashtag) {
      try {
        url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/?__a=1";
        const response = await axios.get(url, {
          headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
        });
        const edges = response.data.graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges;
        const updatedEdges = await Promise.all(
          edges.map(async (edge) => {
            edge.imageBase64 = await convertURLToBase64(edge.node.thumbnail_src);
            return edge;
          })
        );
        console.log("updatedEdges: " + updatedEdges);
        return updatedEdges;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: " + error.message);
      }
    }
    
    function convertURLToBase64(url) {
      console.log("converting URL " + url + " to base64");
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
            rej("Ups!");
            return;
          }
          console.log("there was no error receiving image");
          data =
            "data:" +
            response.headers["content-type"] +
            ";base64," +
            Buffer.from(body).toString("base64");
          // console.log(data);
          res(data);
        });
      });
    }
```